# Problems with object's types

Tags: java, object

I want to use objects in Java, but even I read some tutorials, I don't get it.

```
public class FileIO {

    FileIO parameter[] = new FileIO;

        public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ReadSettings() {

            parameter.add(param.get(1));
        }

    private FileIO add(String string) {

        parameter = string;

        return parameter;
    }
}
```

The problem is: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to FileIO`

I can understand it, but I can't change the type to String. Anyway not really, because then, I cant use the `add` methode.

It would be great if anybody could briefly explain it to me. I'm sure it's a classic beginner question.

Comment: New fileio is not  valid array initialization

Comment: Read a tutorial/book from the beginning and carefully.

Comment: I think you should try to find someone to help you in this very first beginning to explain java for you in person.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send a `String` object *string* under a `FileIO` one *parameter* in below method:

```
private FileIO add(String string) {

    parameter = string;

    return parameter;
}
```

This won't let your code compile in addition to many other problems that can be seen from prima-facie!

Answer (score 1):

Well you are trying to assign `String` object in `FileIO` and that is why you are facing exception. I am assuming you wants to store the list of string parameters. You can do something like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileIO {

    List<String> parameter ;
    public List<String> readSetting(List<String> params){
        if(params == null)
            return parameter;
        if(parameter == null){
            parameter = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        for(String element: params)
            parameter.add(element);
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

**Note** I would strongly suggest you to use start with some good book on Java.

Comment: yeah, this is more or less how it was bevore I wanted to use objects. However, I tried to assign this object a String, so do the object has to be of the type `String`?

Comment: No object does not need to be string but both object should be of same type